# Array Shape Error

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm sending data from one React component to another, but it's not in the shape/format that I'm expecting and I'm having trouble debugging what the issue is.

I've console logged both what the array should look like, and what it comes through as:

[image]

The array on the top is the "good" array, while the one on the bottom is what my array currently comes through as.

What is the difference between (7) [{}.....]  and [Array(7)]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got a 1 dimensional array and a 2 dimensional array:

```js
const arr1 = [{pv:1}, {pv:2}];
const arr2 = [[{pv:1}, {pv:2}]];

console.log(arr1);
console.log(arr2);
```

Answer (score 0):

> What is the difference between (7) [{}.....] and [Array(7)]?

The first option basically means you have objects within an array. The second option basically means you have an array with an array.

For example the first option could be the following.

```
[
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {}
]
```

The second option could be the following.

```
[
    [
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {},
        {}
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you print the second value like `console.log(secondArray[0])` instead of `console.log(secondArray)` than should look like the first one. Here is the console example:

```
var test1 = [{name:1,pv:25},{name:2,pv:75}];
[Object, Object]
var test2 = [[{name:1,pv:25},{name:2,pv:75}]]
[Array[2]]
test2[0]
[Object, Object]
```